# aSmack MUC: Get list of joined rooms after reconnection

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I am building a chat app and I have problem with the MultiUserChat class. The library I am using is downloaded from the google codes.

After the XMPP connectoin is lost, I am automatically leaving all my joined groups

After the reconnection I am trying to use :

```
MultiUserChat.getJoinedRooms(xmpp, "1@test.server.com");
```

so I can all my joined rooms, but I get a NullPointerException.

Anyone have an idea how can rejoined all my joined rooms before I was disconnected?
I thought about storing all my joined in database and then re-joined it after selecting them. Any other idea?

Comment: you have to save them in database, & rejoin them.

Comment: yeah i thought about it, guess i have no other choice... thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kamal is right. `getJoinedRooms()` only returns with a list of rooms if you are connected and joined to some MUC instances. I also recommend to store the MUC JIDs into a database (or just in memory) and rejoin the rooms after a reconnection. [We do the same on GTalkSMS.](http://code.google.com/p/gtalksms/source/browse/src/com/googlecode/gtalksms/xmpp/XmppMuc.java#424)

Comment: Do I have any other options apart from storing the room name in db? In my app I want to show the user all the rooms he joined, but when I call the getJoinedRooms() I am getting a nullpointer exception.